# Why is this logic wrong for Integer palindrome

Tags: java, integer, palindrome

> Refer below Java code for palindrome. 
>     This is to check if the code logic is right or wrong

```
/* Please expalin why this logic is wrong*/

public class IntegerIsPalindrome {
    public static boolean numPalindrome(int x){
        String ParseNum = Integer.toString(x);
        int lenPar = ParseNum.length();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < ParseNum.length();i++){
            if(ParseNum.charAt(0) != ParseNum.charAt(lenPar -1 -i)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean result = numPalindrome(323);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: I suspect `ParseNum.charAt(0)` should be `ParseNum.charAt(i)`.

Comment: With `ParseNum.charAt(0)` , you are always comparing against the first character. Try `ParseNum.charAt(i)` and use `i < ParseNum.length()/2` as the end condition of your loop .

Comment: Yeah its running fine now I did wrong. I just wanted to ask that is it the right way to do the check of the Integer palindrome . I thought we would need modulus and divide logic to check the logic . Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you always compare the first character. Specifically:

```
ParseNum.charAt(0)...
```

You should change this to:

```
ParseNum.charAt(i)...
```

Looking into 323, the first character, '3', and the last, '3', is compared. Then, the first '3' is compared with the '2', resulting in false.

Comment: Thanks , appreciate it . I just saw that . its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate loop upto ParseNum.length()/2 is enough.

Ex: If value is 12321,

you should check

charAt[0] with charAt[4] means 1=1

charAt[1] with charAt[3] means 2=2

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < ParseNum.length()/2;i++){
     if(ParseNum.charAt(i) != ParseNum.charAt(lenPar -1 -i)){
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Cool , Yeah nice to know this as well . I did not think of this logic . Nice to Know

Answer (score 0):

you should need to change `ParseNum.charAt(0)` in the for loop into `ParseNum.charAt(i)`

Here the code you can find palindrome easily:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String input = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(isPalindrome(input) ? "palindrome" : "not a palindrome");
  }

  private static boolean isPalindrome(String input)
  {
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = input.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      temp += input.charAt(i);
    }
    return input.equalsIgnoreCase(temp);
  }
}
```